# pynecone self-hosting get websocket error

Tags: nginx, self-hosting, pynecone

This is the document for self-hosting In fact, from the [document](https://pynecone.app/docs/hosting/self-hosting),
I don't quite understand the meaning of each field in pcconfig.py.

Is there any demonstration of self-hosting?
Or is there a more complete official document?

This is mine.

**pcconfig.py**

```py
config = pc.Config(
    app_name="myapp",
    api_url="http://myhost:8100",
    bun_path="$HOME/.bun/bin/bun",
    db_url="sqlite:///pynecone.db",
)
```

I use nginx on my website. It gets the error message.

```py
WebSocket connection to 'wss://myhost:8100/event/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed
```

I don't know what's going on, but it just won't work,
and I can't quite make out what the file says.

Is anything wrong on my pcconfig.py?
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow :) I hope you enjoy here. 
May you show some of your nginx settings?

Comment: Tks! I will edit the article later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I can share my experience of the self-hosting by nginx briefly.
And if you want to have detailed information, you can read this
[article](https://hackmd.io/@milochen0418/pynecone-self-hosting).

## Scenario

#### My Resources

- I only have a host with the IP **111.123.xxx.33.**   (*In my real case, I run on the linode and it is fully linux*)
- In the host, it can fully run pynecone project well.
- My domain name is **mydomain.net**
- I already have my SSL certificate /xxx/xxx/fullchain.pem and /xxx/xxx/privkey.pem.   (*In my real case, I use Let's Encrypt SSL and managed by Certbot every 3 months*)
- I can setup my DNS for my domain name.   (*In my real case, I use router-53*)
- In the host, no one use ports **3711** and **8701**.

#### My Goal

For a pinecone project, it will finally build to frontend part and backend part. And I hope to achieve the following goal.

- I only want to run frontend and backend on one host with IP **111.123.xxx.33**.
- User can open my service from **https://xxxxx-frontend.mydomain.net**
- I hope pynecone's frontend run on port **3711**
- I hope pynecone's backend run on port **8701**

To achieve this goal with the current resource, we have the following 3 steps to complete this mission.

### 1. DNS Setting

my host's IP is **111.123.xxx.33**
And I can add the two A record on DNS.

- **xxxxx-frontend.mydomain.net** -> **111.123.xxx.33**
- **xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net** -> **111.123.xxx.33**

*The two domain is with the same IP*

### 2. Pynecone Project

#### pcconfig.py

```py
import pynecone as pc
my_deploy_config = pc.Config(
    app_name="myapp",
    port=3711,
    backend_port=8701,
    api_url="https://xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net",
    bun_path="$HOME/.bun/bin/bun",
    db_url="sqlite:///pynecone.db",
    env=pc.Env.PROD,
)
config = my_deploy_config
```

This file give the following information.

- frontend will service in **http://localhost:3711**
- backend will service in **http://localhost:8701**
- The frontend’s source code will communicate with the backend on
  **https://xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net**

#### pc commands to start project

- pc init
- pc run

### 3. Nginx Setting

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Insert the following to include the setting.

```
include /somepath/my-nginx-sites-enabled/*
```

#### /somepath/my-nginx-sites-enabled/xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net

```
server{
    server_name xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8701;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
   }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /xxx/xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /xxx/xxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The above set the following 4 things.

- SSL support
- fully WebSocket Support
- HTTP support
- **xxxxx-backend.mydomain.net** -> **http://localhost:8701**
  (this is pynecone's backend according to your pcconfig.py)

#### /somepath/my-nginx-sites-enabled/xxxxx-frontend.mydomain.net

```
server{
    server_name xxxxx-frontend.mydomain.net;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3711;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /xxx/xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /xxx/xxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The above set the following 4 things.

- SSL support
- fully WebSocket Support
- HTTP support
- **xxxxx-frontend.mydomain.net** -> **http://localhost:3711**
  (this is pynecone's frontend according to your pcconfig.py)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can complete my self-hosting with this setting.